# Bug in making web note

Tags: css, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

When making a web note using default tool in Edge and saving the note to OneNote. The alignment of the note is incorrect, a margin is added in the left of the page. The annotation is also displayed with a offset.

Is there any solution for this bug ? Thanks.

Machine: Surface book
OS info: Windows 10 pro, ver. 1703. 
OS build: 15063.138

Capture:

[image: Capture]

Comment: For reporting bug, you may want to reach https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/

Comment: I've tried to submit issue to that website several times, but failed. @HaibaraAi